# jQuery AJAX: load HTML into DIV element after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i would like to load (or be visible) an HTML/ASP.NET email form after the user clicked in a link/button. I have used this code but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#imgMail").click(function (htm) {
            $.get("mailform.html"),
                $("#mailForm").append(htm)); //i have tryed also with .html() function.
        });
    });
</script>
```

where #imgMail is the ID of the link/button and the #mailForm is the ID of the DIV element into load the content.

How can i resolve this problem?
P.S. The elements are not into a form tag.

Thanks.

Comment: I have used also the @Ajax.ActionLink() method of ASP.NET MVC but it doesn't load content into DIV but load directly the html page as a "postback event", in a new window.

Comment: For starters, you could take a look at the examples at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: @jhonraymos: Excuse me for my bad English, but it isn't my first language. I'm a student, i'm learning :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#imgMail").click(function() {
            $.get("mailform.html",function(data){
                $("#mailForm").append(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I posted the same answer - for some reason I didn't get the notification (again)... no intention

Comment: I already solved, thanks anyway. I have forgot function(htm) after get. Error of distraction :-)

Comment: @fpellegrino if it works than click on the right mark below the votes

Comment: I have clicked however I already solved. I have forgot function(htm) after get. Error of distraction. However thanks anyway :-)